# Redirección de paginas con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

La cosa es que estoy haciendo un proyecto web, con HTML + CSS + JS,
y ya tengo un login, y guardo info en un *LocalStorage*, ya valido que el usuario si esta registrado, y requiero que después de eso sea redirigido a otra pagina (pagina que también he hecho ya, la cosa es como lo redirijo a esa pagina (Se llama `Galeria.html`) sin importar que sea un proyecto local, y funcione siempre igual, los 2 archivos están a el mismo nivel en jerarquía de carpetas.

Lo he intentado con `window.location.href = "Galeria.html`
con `window.location.replace("Galeria.html")` y nada ha funcionado.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
function Login(){
    if(typeof(localStorage) != "undefined"){
        if(L_Pass.value == JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(L_Email.value))[0]){
            window.location.replace("Galeria.html");
            alert("LOGIN EXITOSO!");
            
        }else{
            alert("Algo and malo manito");
        }
    }else{
        alert("No es posible logearte, por favor intenta con otro navegador");
    }
}
```

Abrí la consola en el navegador, y puse:

```
window.location.replace("Galeria.html");
```

Y si funcionó.

Comment: En tu función te falta una llave de cierre. Además ¿hay algún error en la consola?

Comment: ¿Cómo te falla? esa forma de obtener del localStorage un dato se me hace demasiado compleja, ¿qué hay en `localStorage.getItem(L_Email.value))[0]`?

Comment: @anythingg, esta completa, fue error al pasarla aqui

Comment: @PabloLozano, lo que pasa es que guarde los datos con un JSON.stringify, y si lo hago sin el JSON.parse, no me funciona, ya que guardo un array

Comment: @PabloLozano, no me redirige, pero no sale ningun error en consola, solo se queda en la misma pagina, a parte de que se recarga